# Heroku Django: Handling static files. Could not import settings 'my_django_app/settings.py'

Tags: django, static, heroku

I am Django newbie and I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku. It works fine when DEBUG = True (django handles static files). But now I'm setting DEBUG = false and trying to get Heroku to handle static files, but I'm hitting an error.

As per this [blog](http://matthewphiong.com/managing-django-static-files-on-heroku) and the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047054/heroku-handling-static-files-in-django-app), I added this to my Procfile and added the required settings to my settings.py:

> ```
> web: python my_django_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; bin/gunicorn_django --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT my_django_app/settings.py
> ```

But when I push my app, it crashes and I see this in the heroku logs:

> ```
> 2012-03-23T21:55:57+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Could not import settings 'my_django_app/settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The settings path should be a Python module path, not a filesystem path. `my_django_app.settings` is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that as well, but I get this error:
`module not found 2012-03-25T00:52:44+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ImportError("Could not import se
ttings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
2012-03-25T00:52:44+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Could not import settings 'my_django_app.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named my_django_app.settings`

Answer (score 0):

Most like the problem here is your django app name is not "my_django_app". Make sure you replace "my_django_app" with your app name.