# Django on Heroku - Broken Admin Static Files

Tags: django, heroku, django-admin

I have a Django app running on Heroku/Cedar, configured as per the instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Using gunicorn as per Heroku's instructions fails to include the static files required for Django's admin to function. I can change the Procfile to "manage.py run_gunicorn" for local development, but that doesn't fly on Heroku.

I've searched all over for a fix - is there some way to include the admin static files without throwing them on S3 with my other static files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use runserver and configure your app with DEBUG=True, then it will serve the admin files just like on your development machine. However, this is definitely not the recommended way to do it, and I would suggest that you put them on S3.

Using the django-storages app it's very easy to configure collectstatic to automatically push all the admin files to S3. You can find directions [here](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote-storages/)

Answer (score 8):

Check out this post: http://matthewphiong.com/managing-django-static-files-on-heroku

If that doesn't work for you try adding the following to your urls.py after the normal url pattern tuple. Make sure you have your STATIC_ROOT set and you've run collect static on your local environment all before pushing to heroku.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
 )
```

Comment: For me, using Django 1.5.1, ['django.contrib.staticfiles.views'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve) worked whereas 'django.views.static.serve' did not.

Comment: Thanks for that note - I think the path changed in 1.5

Answer (score 8):

just add these instead

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

using django 1.4.1

Comment: Worked with Version: 3.1.5 as well. :)  Specifically add it to the same urlpatterns list containing "path('admin/', admin.site.urls),".

Comment: Worked as a charm

Answer (score 6):

It seems little late compared to the asked date. But I got into this issue and spent 30 mins on what I did wrong. So here it is the magic solution for those who might fall in this trap.

There is some problem with Heroku's `django.contrib.staticfiles.urls`

**SOLUTION**

You need to install `dj-static` ([Link to download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dj-static)) on your Heroku setup.
**It's a Django middleware utility that allows to properly serve static assets from production with a WSGI server like Gunicorn.**

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Adding this to the setup is actually part of the Heroku tutorial. I completed these instructions and still have the same problem in admin, so this does not seem to be a valid solution.

Comment: It worked for me at that time. I'm not sure why wouldn't it work now.

Comment: Worked! Excelent bro!

Answer (score 3):

create 'static' folder into your 'project_directory'.

set the 'STATIC_ROOT' path in 'settings.py' file which can serve your admin-site's static files.

```
STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static'))
```

Add STATIC_ROOT in '/urls.py'

```
from django.conf import settings
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

Run the following command that will copy all the admin static files into project's static folder.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Now do git add, commit and push heroku master.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying to Heroku without using whitenoise (which I would suggest), definitely use dj_static https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dj-static!

I spent the past 3 hours trying to serve my files to heroku and dj_static worked within a matter of 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I got django admin working with following edits

urls.py(at the end)

```
import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
)
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

'django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve'

instead of

'django.views.static.serve'

Answer (score 0):

Follow this to fix all static related issues with Django and heroku.

In your `settings.py` paste this at the end

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    )
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
    )

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Your template for a particular app should be in `app_name/templates/app_name/`

When you render template this is how you will specify `template name`

in `views.py`

```
.....
return render(request,'app_name/template_name.html',context)
```

For `static files` place your files here:

`project_folder/app_name/static/app_name/css`

`project_folder/app_name/static/app_name/js`

`project_folder/app_name/static/app_name/img`

to access your static file use path `app_name/css/style_name.css`

If you follow this, all your static files will load up fine in heroku as well as in your local development machine.