# Heroku django - messed up project structure

Tags: django, heroku, python-2.7

I've deployed my app on heroku (cedar stack) and all worked fine until a few days ago, When i noticed that my static files are not being served (appear with code 'canceled'). Next thing i noticed is that my project suddenly had new folders on same level as manage.py : admin/, css/, img/ and js/. I didnt create admin at all, using a buildin django admin site and didnt modify it in any way. I did create css, img and js folders under static/ inside my project, and its still there along with all its content. It's like all the folders in static/ got copied to manage.py level.

Running `heroku run ls -l`  shows  same changes on heroku. I suspect those changes cause troubles in serving static files.

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

shows all files copied no problem.

my static dirs settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

I dont use S3 yet.

How to remove those files? What caused those dirs to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Django application is deployed to Heroku, `collectstatic` is automatically run ([Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)). This collects all the static assets from your installed apps (including `django.contrib.admin`) and copies them to the `STATIC_ROOT`.

Check your `STATIC_ROOT` setting. It is probably not set correctly.

[Here is a tutorial](http://wavesandmaps.com/utilizing-s3-for-a-heroku-django-app/) on using S3 with your static files.

Comment: Thank you, following your advice i was able to solve the problem ;) I posted my solution as another answer to clarify how i made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308985/django-on-heroku-broken-admin-static-files) i learned that all this mess was caused by changing DEBUG to FALSE. Following Ohads' advice i checked my STATIC_ROOT setting, and as you can see, it wasn't set. Those are my fixed settings:

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(SETTINGS_PATH+'/static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Adding:

```
if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

in myapp/urls.py solved my problem.