# Serving static files on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm writing a Python app for heroku.
Flask is used for the web component of the app.

My problem is that I can't find a way to serve static files.
I don't want to do it through flask because that is very inefficient.

I'm also using gunicorn. How would I set up serving of static files?

Comment: Heroku could do with offering a suggestion for this in the quick start. As you say, people say "Don't use flask! nginx (or whatever) directly!" - and then Heroku say "You don't need nginx! Our Cloud Platform (R) (TM) (C) handles all that for you!" ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using Amazon s3 for storing static and media files. A similar question and answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569144/proper-way-to-handle-static-files-and-templates-for-django-on-heroku). [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) is heroku's documentation of using s3. Then you might want to disable automatic collectstatic [instructions here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) so collectstatic isn't run every time you push to heroku.  Hope this helps.