# Heroku static files not loading, Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to push [my Django project](https://help-the-needy.herokuapp.com/) to Heroku, but it isn't loading the staticfiles.

I used [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) to setup the things, everything is fine but I'm not able to fix the issue with static files.

My directory structure is like this

```
help_the_needy
    help_the_needy
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
    Procfile  
    requirements.txt  
    static
        css
        font-awesome
        fonts  
        img  
        js
    templates
        base.html
        display_list2.html
        index.html
```

[Here](https://github.com/tapasweni-pathak/SO) is the complete code (all files).

[This](https://github.com/tapasweni-pathak/SO/blob/master/help_the_needy/settings.py) is my settings.py.

I tried alot of things to fix this, but nothing seems to work.

When I push it [does copy static files](http://gyazo.com/2348ff11e91e8b58ddcbf7dbb7dacf79) but it's not loading them.

Can someone please point me to my mistake? Where is it wrong?

Comment: did you try to run the command  python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput on the Heroku Django shell? do you get any error?

Comment: Yes. I got no error. (http://gyazo.com/30ea49aeb727054f5dd21265a45ae261).

Comment: u can try: STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles', STATIC_URL = '/static/',
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'../static'),)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates'),)

Comment: @LhAcKg It's not working, same output.

Comment: @TapasweniPathak your root project settings add this code import os and BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

Comment: @TapasweniPathak u can check this python manage.py shell and from mysite.settings import BASE_DIR, print(BASE_DIR)

Comment: @LhAcKg It isn't working. :(

Answer (score 9):

I have been dealing with the same problem too. And here are the 2 things that I changed in my code.

(I'm using Django 1.7)

1) settings.py

I add these lines to the setting files

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
    # Add to this list all the locations containing your static files 
)
```

STATIC_ROOT: this tells Django where to (a) put the static files when you run `python manage.py collectstatic` and (b) find the static files when you run the application

TEMPLATE_DIRS: this tells Django where to look for your static files when it search for statics files when you run `python manage.py collectstatic`

2) wsgi.py

Originally my file was:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxxx.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And I changed it to:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxxx.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Read here for more information on whitenoise: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise

---

Also, remember to install whitenoise:
    `pip install whitenoise==2.0.6`

Before deploying the project, run:
    `python manage.py collectstatic`

This will create a folder indicated by STATIC_ROOT (declared in your settings.py), containing all your static files.

Comment: Since it's been a few years since this answer was posted, here's what worked for me in Django 3.2.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's been a few years since this was posted (and it still pops up when I search for the issue), here's what worked for me in Django 3.2.

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Make sure in settings.py you have

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Add whitenoise to your Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]
```

Make sure the directory you specified as the STATIC_ROOT (staticfiles) exists in your base directory and is not empty.

After that, I committed the changes and Heroku was able to build the static files and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Add whitenoise to requirement.txt.

and also add whitenoise in the middleware of settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', #add whitenoise
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Follow the steps in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Answer (score 0):

Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is wrong. It should be pointing to the actual location of the "static" directory containing the files:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: I did that before, it was not working. I tried os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static') too, it too didn't worked.

I tried both the things again, same output.

Comment: anything else to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like django don't know where your static_root is.
This folder is autogenerated when you fire `manage.py collectstatic`
Make sure that the folders `static` and `templates` are inside your django app. You didn't created a django app to put this folders into. You created a django project the next step is to create a django app with something like this `python manage.py startapp polls`

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the Django project directory:
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
# Absolute filesystem path to the top-level project folder:
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static_root'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `urls.py` file lacks the setting to manage and route requests for static resources.

in order to provide access to static resorces you must add to `urlpatterns` of `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

Comment: That is for development only.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i know but Heroku requires this configuration, another answer can be found here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047054/heroku-handling-static-files-in-django-app

Comment: No, that linked answer is simply wrong. The correct answer is provided by [Heroku's own documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) and the OP is already following it most of the way.