# heroku python and highlight js not working

Tags: javascript, python, css, heroku

I'm following the basic Heroku tutorial using Python (Django) to stand up a web page. I eventually want to blog, and to include code snippets, so I wanted to include `highlight.js` to make the code look prettier.

However, I cannot figure out how or where to include the `<link ... "style/...css" />` and/or `<script ...highlight.min.js" ></script>` to get things to render - I end up with plain code-text even though my `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` tags have `hljs` class appended, and I can see that the stylesheet and script are linked correctly.

Instead of trying to copy and paste 16 different files with 40 lines each, I think it's easiest to just link to my testing page.
[page which should be using highlight js but isn't](https://serene-citadel-4542.herokuapp.com/blogs/1/).

Note also that I'm trying to use a `highlight.js` stylesheet called `androidstudio`; the giveaway that it's working is that the code background will be gray/black, and some of the words will be bold and different colors (ie the entire point of highlight js).

This question is different from [this local static file question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047054/heroku-handling-static-files-in-django-app) because I'm trying to use `//cdnjs` files, that is, publicly-hosted `js` and `css` files.

Comment: I'm partly a dope - I forgot to update my heroku with the `//cdnjs` links, but they are there now; same problem still and I'm using publicly-hosted `js` and `css` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the quote (`"`) before `stylesheet`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.1.0/styles/androidstudio.min.css" />
```

When you view source using Firefox it highlights (no pun intended) your error:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that got default highlighting, which is definitely progress; it still doesn't use the `androidstudio` highlighting though (again, telltale sign is dark background). I put the `default.min.js` first

Comment: DOH. So, including your `<link ...>` helped show me my mistake: instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` I was missing the opening `"` before `stylesheet`.  It appears to work even without the `default`, for the record.

Comment: Ahh haha, we both answered the same thing at the same time. Thanks so much, this was driving me insane!