# Server MEDIA (profile pic users) on Django with DEBUG = False

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, django-settings, django-media

I was deployng my project to Heroku and set up the `DEBUG` option to `False`. Until that, all was working ok. But, now, I can't server the user profile images. I want to **server only with the Django**, not with Apache or Nginx. I know that it's not the best option, but I don't need the best way to do this, so, if exists any way to server this with only the Django, will better to me.

This is my `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'saga', 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

This is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    #URLs
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And I think that's goodn say that I'm using the WhiteNoise to server the Static Files on Heroku.

Comment: you can run your server in mode `--insecure`, maybe duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047054/heroku-handling-static-files-in-django-app

Comment: How can I execute this command at Heroku? The post shows how to server the static files and I'm already serving them. The problem is with the user's uploads, because they don't work when I set `DEBUG = False`.