# Heroku Django requests static files that don't exist

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles, collectstatic

Using whitenoise for managing production static files. 
Django==2.1.4
whitenoise==4.1.2

My production server is requesting static files that look like mine (ie `bootstrap.min.js`) but have characters on the end (ie. `bootstrap.min.xyz789.js`).

I notice that in my `STATIC_ROOT` directory there are already a bunch of these (ie. `bootstrap.min.abc123.js`) but they don't match the ones that my heroku site is requesting (ie. `bootstrap.min.xyz789.js`). I ran collectstatic both locally and in heroku but no luck. What are these files and why don't they match?

PS - no issue locally only in heroku.

Comment: Does this answer your question, [Heroku - Handling static files in Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047054/heroku-handling-static-files-in-django-app)

Comment: I got the answer from that question to work but it did not fix the issue. Do you have any idea how/why the files with extra characters exist or are being requesting in prod but not in dev?

Comment: Which staticfile-storage did you configure? Django's ManifestStaticFilesStorage? The compressed one by whitenoise?